# Configure the OS X Server from .pkg postinstall script

Tags: install, osx-server, server.app, script, apache

I make a .pkg-installer for a product that extends the Apache server in OS X.

From the postinstall script in the .pkg I'm currently able to configure the default setup of Yosemite and El Capitan, by adding a product.conf file in the `/etc/apache2/other` folder.

To load the new configuration I simply do the following from the postinstall script:

```
launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist #if not loaded
apachectl stop #if already started
apachectl start
```

Installing the OS X Server changes the way Apache is configured, so the above approach fails.
So, how can I configure the OS X Server from my postinstall script to do the same?

Comment: What version of Server.app and what version of OS X? Your script is likely going to fork based on SIP and also depend on what "extending" means in practice?

Comment: As I´m deploying for OS X in general I would like the script to work for all versions of the Server.app that is able to run on El Capitan and Yosemite. "Extending Apache" doesn't mean anything else than loading cgi, mime and alias apache modules and creating Aliases and Scriptaliases within a `product.conf` file. Could you explain what you mean by "fork based on SIP"?

Comment: @bmike SIP = System Integrity Protection? Fork = Fail?

Comment: SIP - is exactly what you guesses. No one likes to be "forked" - also the need to code an OS check to see which "fork" to take. If 10.10, do this and that, if 10.11, do something else - type of "fork".

Comment: Ah, in that case I hope that Apple gives some way of dealing with SIP in a user friendly way. My approach seems to work for plain El Capitan, as I was able to do a `launchctl unload` followed by `launchctl load` without issues.

Comment: @bmike With help from @grgarside I found that forking can be done for the Server.app installed by checking on the result from `serverinfo -q --software`. I tested and found that there are no need to do anything with SIP to add to the configuration of the Websites service of the Server.app.

Comment: I am so happy - feel free to edit in your solution to my post or self-answer the question. That george is sharp and I also learn a lot from his help.

Comment: Just added my script-code to the end of your answer. Good teamwork @bmike Hopefully it could help others as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The automating of server.app components is quite trivial since you can use `serveradmin` to do the heavy lifting.

```
  sudo serveradmin start web;
```

Asking a service to start if it's already running is harmless/idempotent.

To fork between the Apache configured by the Server.app and the "normal state" do the following:

```
if serverinfo -q --software; then
   cp product.conf /Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/other
   serveradmin stop web
   serveradmin start web
else
   cp product.conf /etc/apache2/other
   launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
   apachectl stop #if already started
   apachectl start
fi
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess I could expect that I do not need to load any service, as this is done within the `start` command? I will try the following within my script: `serveradmin stop web` then `serveradmin start web`

Comment: Yes - a stop would probably be best if you want to be sure it's restarted @JoachimBratteli

Comment: I copied my configuration file from `/etc/apache2/other/` to `/Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/other/`, did a `serveradmin` stop and start, and now It works! . Thanks @bmike