# How to evaluate the state of the OS X Server.app from a shell script?

Tags: macos, server.app, script, command-line

I need to evaluate if the OS X Server.app has been installed and if it has been started or not. This I need to do from within a shell script. 
I could check for existing folder names, but I would expect it cannot truly make sure that the Server.app is installed and up and running so that I can run the `serveradmin` command.
Anyone with a suggestion?

This is a follow-up question to my previous question: [Configure the OS X Server from .pkg postinstall script](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/209461/configure-the-os-x-server-from-pkg-postinstall-script)

Comment: I don't have OSX Server, but `serverinfo` might help. And you could test for the existence of `serveradmin` and assume "no server" if it is missing.

Comment: Checking on the result of running `serverinfo -q --software` helped. Thank you for helping @patrix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be determined by running the following command:

```
serverinfo --configured
```

To evaluate the result of the command within a shell script use the -q option and encapsulate it in an if-statement:

```
 if serverinfo -q --configured;
 then
    echo configured; 
 else
    echo not_configured;
 fi
```

The `serverinfo` gives two options to determine if the Server.app is just installed or configured:

```
--software [PATH]
    Returns status 0 if the root volume has a server OS installed
    Use optional argument PATH to specify mountpoint of alternate volume
--configured [PATH]
    Returns status 0 if the server is configured
    Use optional argument PATH to specify mountpoint of alternate volume
```

So if the `serveradmin --configured` command "fails", you could check if is installed:

```
 if serverinfo -q --configured;
 then
    echo configured; 
 else
    if serverinfo -q --software;
    then
       echo installed;
    else
       echo not_installed;
    fi
 fi
```

Comment: Thanks @grgarside Based on this command I will test if this could be a solution in my shell script:    `OUTPUT=$(serverinfo --software)
$if [ $OUTPUT = "This system has server software installed." ]; then  
   cp product.conf /Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/other/  
   #stop and start the websites service  
   serveradmin stop web  
   serveradmin start web  
fi`

Comment: @JoachimBratteli There's no need to check for string output—you can use the -q option such as `if serverinfo -q --software; then echo enabled; else echo disabled; fi`

Comment: With your remarks my script has been tested and found to be working for both Yosemite without the Server.app installed and El Capitan that has the Server.app installed. Thanks @grgarside