# Macos Big Sur port 80 permission denied with root

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, big-sur

im facing this problem where im trying to start a server on port 80 of a Macbook Pro with MacOS Big Sur and im getting permission denied.

I tried running with sudo and also doing "sudo su" and then running the server.

I'm trying running a Nuxt (node js) server

```
$ sudo npm run dev
Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 127.0.0.1:80
```

Should i unlock something?

Comment: How do you start your server (exact command), where do you get the error message?

Comment: Im running "sudo npm run dev" and im getting "Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 127.0.0.1:80"

Comment: Is something else already running on port 80? Does it work if you use a higher port above 1024?

Comment: With port 1000 for ex, i get the same permission denied and with port 1025 it works perfect

Answer (score 1):

For years I have been running a local node.js server on port 80 with

`sudo npm run`

After upgrading `npm` to `7.6.3` from `6.14.11` i also get a permission denied error. The error disappeared after downgrading back to `6.14.11`.

No sure if this was an intended change to run `node` on a port below 1024.

Answer (score 0):

No, everything is working as intended. You need sudo to have a command line process listen on low ports. There’s nothing you want to unlock here as this is a protective feature.

I usually just test on ports higher than 1024 to avoid this risk entirely until it’s time to write a [proper wrapper script](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/362812/5472), but all three options are just as suitable. (Use sudo, use setuid permissions, change the port listen number)

To use sudo - run a shell first, then the npm command

```
sudo -s
npm run dev
exit
```

Comment: The issue is that im running the server with sudo. Thats why im asking

Comment: You can’t `sudo` the `npm` ince that calls another process - try `sudo -s` followed by the `npm` command  @FaustoSanchez

Comment: I get the same error with that command